# Writing SQL Query for Menu System

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a menu system for an application and I am a little stuck on how to go about creating a database query.

Here is what my Table looks like:

[image]

The green rows are "Parent Menus" and the others are children.

I need help writing a TSQL query that sorts the data shown to have the parent shown and then its children (if any).

Sorting order will be:

Parent then by Children of Parent, then by Order (numerical value).

Here is what my database looks like:

[image]

Comment: At least you can execute `SELECT @@VERSION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution ([sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/19441)):

```
WITH RecursiveCTE
AS(
    SELECT  crt.id, crt.title, crt.parentID, crt.[order],
            -- 1 AS menu_level,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000), '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),crt.[order]) + '/') AS overall_order
    FROM    @Menu crt
    WHERE   crt.parentID = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  cld.id, cld.title, cld.parentID, cld.[order],
            -- prt.menu_level + 1 AS menu_level,
            prt.overall_order + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),cld.[order]) + '/'
    FROM    @Menu cld -- cld = Child
    INNER JOIN RecursiveCTE prt ON cld.parentID = prt.id -- prt = Parent
)
SELECT  *
        ,CONVERT(HIERARCHYID, overall_order) AS hid_overall_order -- SQL2008+ You could convert to HIERARCHYID
FROM    RecursiveCTE
ORDER BY hid_overall_order
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0) -- Default MAXRECURSION is 100
```

Results:

```
id title           parentID    order overall_order
-- --------------- ----------- ----- -------------
11 Home            0           1     /1/
12 Settings        0           2     /2/
13 Change Password 12          4     /2/4/
14 Update Profile  12          5     /2/5/
15 Search          0           3     /3/
16 Options         15          6     /3/6/
```

Comment: can i put the final output into xml? 
FOR XML PATH('menu'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT('root')

Comment: @CarlHussey: I don't see any requirement regarding XML output. You can try :-)

Comment: Well I tried adding it after the last select statement and it didnt like it

Comment: @BogdanSahlean your query could give incorrect ordering, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/19430 - 15 will go before 4. After you'll change it - it will be mirroring of my answer :)

Comment: @CarlHussey: You should post the full problem from the start including  the information regarding the XML output. Every detail can be important. And it isn't nice to say "it didnt like it" without saying the reason[s] when some people try to help you.

Answer (score 2):

for sql server you can do recursive query, something like this:

```
with cte as (
    select
        m.id, m.parent_id, m.title,
        right('00000' + cast(m.ordering as nvarchar(max)), 5) as ordering
    from menu as m
    where m.parent_id is null

    union all

    select
        m.id, m.parent_id, m.title,
        c.ordering + '.' + right('00000' + cast(m.ordering as nvarchar(max)) , 5) as ordering
    from menu as m
        inner join cte as c on c.id = m.parent_id
)
select *
from cte
order by ordering
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0057f/2)

Comment: hm, i'm still a little confused on how to adapt this to my table :/

Comment: Why? Just add other columns to select

Comment: It seemed to give me more data than what I expected at the end: http://carl.me/menu2.png

Comment: weird, that returned nothing now

Comment: @CarlHussey see sql fiddle demo, you have to join cte on cte.id = menu.parent_id

Comment: I must be doing something wrong or my table isnt set up the same.. i copied what you had and just added some extra fields and it still doesnt work ;/ your answer is right but i cant get it to match up

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b9ad/2

"Change Password and Testing" should both be under "Settings"

Comment: could you create sqlfiddle.com example with your data? I'll fix it and we'll see what wrong

Comment: you haven't used main part with ordering and also your Testing row have order = null. See fixed sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b9ad/5